# How to use Activity Monitor to view Network activity

Tags: network, activity-monitor

My Activity Monitor is showing that something is downloading, I can the download activity on the graph and the overall speed is shown as 'Data received/sec.  But I'm stuck trying to figure out which process it is that's using the network?

I can sort by 'Rcvd Bytes' or 'Rcvd Packets', but those would seem to be cumulative totals. Isn't there some kind of '% Network' column??

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitor is, as you have discovered, very limited outside the CPU and memory tabs.

For a GUI application (with free trial period) you can use:

- One of the many menubar "show stats" apps. [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) is the best.
- A firewall tool which includes network monitoring. [LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) is the most popular and arguably the best.

If you are prepared for a very difficult to use Terminal command, you can use `nettop` which is included with macOS. I find it hard to recommend.